# SEO ranking for drop-down containing product text, which can be viewable or hidden by website visitor?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, seo, spam-prevention

I'm building a site on behalf of a watch company who want to have their images very prominently displayed on each page.

They also want product descriptions to be ranked well in terms of SEO, but they like the concept I have presented to them in using the JQuery 'A Different Top Navigation' (by Connor Zwick), for both the navigation AND a way of allowing users to VIEW and HIDE the product description for images. Checking out the demo will give you an idea of my plan:

Tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/a-different-top-navigation/

Demo here: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/386_navigation/top-nav-demo/index.html#

So, with reference to another stackoverflow answer about crawlers indexing only the first level of hidden links, is this technique impractical for SEO because the product descriptions may not be indexed due to the association with keyword spamming in hidden boxes?

Thanks for any suggestions you can provide,

Dale M. Rollinson

Comment: All I can say is that that navigation is annoying as hell.  I didn't see the "X" and was trying to close it (which is not possible without the X for some reason).  When I closed it, my mouse naturally went off to the left, at which point it opened again.  Okay, clicked X and moved straight down quickly!  THEN I was going up to my address bar to navigate away from that stupid thing and it opened again!  Ugh.  I hope you're going to make some usability improvements to that nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard that bit about only the first level of hidden elements being traversed by search engine crawlers.  If that's true, you can avoid setting the style with CSS and use javascript to do it instead (crawlers don't run JS).

```
<nav>
stuff
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('nav').hide();
</script>
```

I placed it in the document like this so it's run immediately after the nav is loaded on the page.  Do not wait for document ready on this.  You could also put it at the bottom of your  if you so chose.  I'd maybe do that too.